# Angular - How to apply [ngStyle] conditions

Tags: angular, ng-style

I have a div that I want to style based on a condition.

If styleOne is true I want a background colour of red. If StyleTwo is true, I want the background colour to be blue. I've got half of it working with the below code.

```html
    <div id="myDiv" [ngStyle]="styleOne && {'background-color': 'red'}">
```

Is it possible to add a condition to say:

- if styleOne is true, do this
- if styleTwo is true, do this?

**Edit**

I think i've resolved it. It works. Not sure if it's the best way:

```html
<div id="div" [ngStyle]="styleOne && {'background-color': 'red'} || styleTwo && {'background-color': 'blue'}">
```

Answer (score 279, accepted):

For a single style attribute, you can use the following syntax:

```html
<div [style.background-color]="style1 ? 'red' : (style2 ? 'blue' : null)">
```

I assumed that the background color should not be set if neither `style1` nor `style2` is `true`.

---

Since the question title mentions `ngStyle`, here is the equivalent syntax with that directive:

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': style1 ? 'red' : (style2 ? 'blue' : null) }">
```

Answer (score 61):

You can use an inline if inside your ngStyle:

```
[ngStyle]="styleOne?{'background-color': 'red'} : {'background-color': 'blue'}"
```

A better way in my opinion is to store your background color inside a variable and then set the background-color as the variable value:

```
[style.background-color]="myColorVaraible"
```

Answer (score 41):

```
[ngStyle]="{'opacity': is_mail_sent ? '0.5' : '1' }"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<ion-col size="12">
  <ion-card class="box-shadow ion-text-center background-size"
  *ngIf="data != null"
  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + data.headerImage + ')'}">

  </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'top': yourVar === true ? widthColumHalf + 'px': '302px' }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[ngStyle]="{'margin-left': step.stepNo == 1 ? '-15px' : '-30px'}"
```