# Interpolating a variable as an inline style parameter of the component template?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

This is the component template:

```
<div style="max-width: 100rem;
            margin-top: 5rem;
            min-height: 20rem; 
            overflow: hidden;">
    <img style="width: 100%; 
                height: auto;  
                margin: -20% 0 -20% 0;" 
        [src]="src">
</div>
```

And the component class:

```
    import { Input, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'image',
      templateUrl: './image.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./image.component.scss']
    })
    export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() src;
      @Input() crop = "-20%"

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
    }
```

I thought it would be possible to add the `crop` input value into the template like this:

```
    margin: {{crop}} 0 {{crop}} 0;"
```

However this does not work.  Thoughts?

Comment: I would suggest looking into [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280975/angular-how-to-apply-ngstyle-conditions) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to interpolate style properties you need to use NgStyle directive like so:

```
<img [ngStyle]="{'margin': margin}"/>
```

and in component

```
get margin() { 
  return `${this.crop} 0 ${this.crop} 0`
}
```

You can take a look on official docs here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Answer (score 1):

NgStyle would be the perfect option, but if you need to stick with your model of execution, you may try using CSS variables to set the margin.

Find the [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubjmsu) where the colour is changed in a similar manner.

hello.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { 
    font-family: Lato;
    color: var(--hello-color); 
  }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() color: string; 

  constructor(public element: ElementRef) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('h1').style.setProperty('--hello-color', this.color);​
  }
}
```

**style.css**

```
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */
:root{
  --hello-color: red;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<hello color="{{ color }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

Comment: That CSS property explanation is sweet!  Thanks for pointing that out!  Will be playing with that for sure.