# How to conditionally change background color of a mat cell in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `mat` table, in which I want to change the `Background color` of a particular cell conditionally.

My HTML:

```html
   <ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
            Status
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Status}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

I have the color value in the "row" variable with `row.statusBgColor`.

I tried with:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
     Status
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell style="background-color: {{row.statusBgColor}}" *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Status}}
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

But that didn't work. Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280975/angular-how-to-apply-ngstyle-conditions) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use ngStyle or style**

Apply this property to mat-cell

1. ngStyle

   **[ngStyle]="{'background-color':row.statusBgColor}"**
2. style

   **[style.backgroundColor]="row.statusBgColor"**

Answer (score 0):

Got it .

```
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                           Status
                        </mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell [style.background-color]="row.statusBgColor" *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Status}} </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>
```